# Translation tool

Tags: android, eclipse

am wondering if is possible to  use a feature on my app that can translate the app to other languages so the user can select through a list of languages so as he can read the app even if he doesnt speak English, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If you use the framework's localization facilities, this will happen automatically based on the user's language setting on their device

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Basically, instead of using string literals in your code (ie. `txt.setText("Something")` or `android:text="Something"`), you create these in your strings.xml file and use the automatically created reference id's.

res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="something">Something</string>
```

Then, you create alternate res/values folders for the other languages you support and create a similar strings.xml file there.

res/values-es/strings.xml

```
<string name="something">Algo</string>
```

Then your layouts and codes would have `txt.setText(R.string.something)` or `android:text="@string/something"`.

You can do the same thing for drawable, layout, menu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"to use a feature on my app that can translate the app to other languages"

I do not think such feature exist from Google. But if you write the app according  [Google's localization guide](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/localizing.html) then you can use our Nativer app, which is designed exactly for that. It takes you language resources - translates with a machine and then let's the crowd to correct it. All these happens in runtime - so you do not need to bother when the language translation finished by the crowd. You can find further info here [transround.com](http://www.transround.com)

Peter